# named parameters with same name

Tags: r

I'm using the 'caret' library to to do some cross validation on some trees.

The library provides a function called `train`, that takes in a named argument "method". Via its ellipsis it's supposed to let other arguments fall through to another function that it calls. This other function (`rpart`) takes an argument of the same name, "method".

Therefore I want to pass two arguments with the same name... and it's clearly failing. I tried to work around things as shown below but I get the error:

"Error in train.default(x = myx, y = myy, method = "rpart2", preProcess = NULL,  : 
  formal argument "method" matched by multiple actual arguments"

any help is much appreciated! thanks!

```
train.wrapper = function(myx, myy, mytrControl, mytuneLenght, ...){
   result = train(
                        x=myx,
                        y=myy,
                        method="rpart2",
                        preProcess=NULL,
                        ...,
                        weights=NULL,
                        metric="Accuracy",
                        trControl=mytrControl,
                        tuneLength=mytuneLenght

                      )
   return (result)
 }
dtree.train.cv = train.wrapper(training.matrix[,2:1777], 
                               training.matrix[,1], 
                               2, method="class")
```

Comment: What does 'train' do with the 'method' argument, other than passing it to rpart?

Comment: train uses "its" method argument to choose which function to call internally... so above, train would internally call the function "rpart" which has a "method" argument of its own and which I'm trying to get to by passing via train's ellipsis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a mock-up of your problem with a `tr` (train) function that calls an `rp` (rpart) function, passing it `...`:

```
rp <- function(method, ...) method
tr <- function(method, ...) rp(...)

# we want to pass 2 to rp:
tr(method=1, method=2) # Error
tr(1, method=2)        # 1, (wrong value!)
tr(method=1, metho=2)  # 2 (Yay!)
```

What magic is this? And why does the last case actually work?! Well, we need to understand how argument matching works in R. A function `f <- function(foo, bar)` is said to have *formal parameters* "foo" and "bar", and the call `f(foo=3, ba=13)` is said to have (actual) *arguments* "foo" and "ba".

R first matches all arguments that have *exactly* the same name as a formal parameter. This is why the first "method" argument gets passed to `train`. Two identical argument names cause an error.

Then, R matches any argument names that partially matches a (yet unmatched) formal parameter. But if two argument names partially match the same formal parameter, that also causes an error. Also, it only matches formal parameters *before* `...`. So formal parameters *after* `...` must be specified using their full names.

Then the unnamed arguments are matched in positional order to the remaining formal arguments.

Finally, if the formal arguments include `...`, the remaining arguments are put into the `...`.

**PHEW!** So in this case, the call to `tr` fully matches `method`, and then pass the rest into `...`. When `tr` then calls `rp`, the `metho` argument partially matches its formal parameter `method`, and all is well!

**...Still**, I'd try to contact the author of `train` and point out this problem so he can fix it properly! Since "rpart" and "rpart2" are supposed to be supported, he must have missed this use case!

I think he should rename his `method` parameter to `method.` or similar (anything longer than "method"). This will still be backward compatible, but allows another `method` parameter to be passed correctly to `rpart`.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy, this is great. From the moment I realized what was happening I knew I'd have to learn about argument matching in R...

I was able to work it out by specifying my response variable as a factor, which in turn caused rpart to default to the method I was trying to set. BUT the documentation for rpart itself states "It is wisest to specify the method directly, especially as more criteria may added to the function in future." So I still think there is room for improvement of caret.

I emailed the author, linked to this page. It's the first question I post and am impressed by the help!

Answer (score 1):

Generally wrappers will pass their parameters in a named list. In the case of `train`, provision for control is passed in the trControl argument. Perhaps you should try:

```
dtree.train.cv = train.wrapper(training.matrix[,2:1777], 
                           training.matrix[,1], 
              2,   # will be positionally matched, probably to 'myTuneLenght'
                           myTrControl=list(method="class") )
```

After your comment I reviewed again the `train` and `rpart` help pages. You could well be correct in thinking that trControl has a different purpose. I am suspicious that you may need to construct your call with a formula since `rpart` only has a formula method. If the y argument is a factor than method="class will be assumed by `rpart`. And ... running modelLookup:

```
modelLookup("rpart2")
     model parameter          label  seq forReg forClass probModel
154 rpart2  maxdepth Max Tree Depth TRUE   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE
```

... suggest to me that a "class" method would be assumed by default as well. You may also need to edit your question to include a data example (perhaps from the `rpart` help page?) if you want further advice.

Comment: I am passing a trainControl object, and I don't think it'll do what you're suggesting it does.

Looking at ?train the documentation describes the ellipses: "... 
arguments passed to the classification or regression routine" whereas the documentation for ?trainControl doesn't mention pass through arguments at all...