# Identically named parameters for nested function calls and ellipsis

Tags: r, parameter-passing, ellipsis

Let's consider the following situation:

```
foo <- function(param, ...)
{
  print(paste("foo:", param))
  bar(...)
}

bar <- function(param = NA) 
{
  print(paste("bar:", param))
}
```

Question: how to call `foo`, so that `foo` gets `param = "foo"` and `bar` gets `param = "bar"`?

Answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575078/named-parameters-with-same-name), one can use partial matching:

```
foo(param = "foo", par = "bar")
[1] "foo: foo"
[1] "bar: bar"
```

But what if using partial matching is not available? For instance,

- rename `param` to `p`;
- add another parameter `para_whatever` to `bar`;
- add another function layer `xyz` with the same signature as `bar`;

and the solution no longer works. What can be done (without modifying the source, of course)?

Illustrating the last option with three nested calls and partial matching failing,

```
foo <- function(param, ...)
{
  print(paste("foo:", param))
  bar(...)
}

bar <- function(param = NA, ...) 
{
  print(paste("bar:", param))
  xyz(...)
}

xyz <- function(param = NA, para_whatever = NA)
{
  print(paste("xyz:", param))
}
```

I'm looking for a call that would produce

```
[1] "foo: foo"
[1] "bar: bar"
[1] "xyz: xyz"
```

The described situation is actually happening under Windows in `install.packages`, that passes `...` to `.install.winbinary`, that calls `download.file`. All three have a parameter `quiet`. Sources for them available [here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/46102b91b35a7befa0cf6cc6abd0da09b86f1621/src/library/utils/R/windows/install.packages.R) and [here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/46102b91b35a7befa0cf6cc6abd0da09b86f1621/src/library/utils/R/packages2.R).

EDIT: To clarify, I have the following use case. I'd like to have a call to `install.packages` that would pass the following parameters:

1. `quiet = FALSE` for `install.packages`
2. `quiet = FALSE` for its nested call to `.install.winbinary`
3. `quiet = TRUE` for its nested call to `download.file`

Comment: Is positional matching (i.e., `..1`) an option for your use case? A call like `foo(param = "foo", param = "bar")` is not possible nor sensible.

Comment: I'm not getting your problem. The `quiet` argument is explicitly passed all along from `install.packages` to `download.packages`.

Comment: @nicola I want `quiet = TRUE` for the first and third function in the chain, `quiet = FALSE` for the second. This may not make much sense, but I'm asking in a general case.

Comment: @Roland Probably. I'm interested in any R native solution, really. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If that is what you want, you should re-write `install.packages`. As I said before, this has not anything to do with `...` or partial matching, since `quiet` is explicitly passed. They do not want you to pass different `quiet` arguments to the three functions.

Comment: Fair point. I can't say I totally agree with the intention, but if it is meant to be like so, so be it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the question, but since you asked for an example of positional matching:

```
foo <- function(param, ...)
{
  print(paste("foo:", param))
  bar(..1)
}

bar <- function(param = NA) 
{
  print(paste("bar:", param))
}

foo(param = "foo", "bar", "baz")
#[1] "foo: foo"
#[1] "bar: bar"
```

**Edit:** If a parameter is passed to two different functions via the ellipsis you can't pass different parameter values to these functions. You need to change the calling function (e.g., you could use `trace`).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that touches the source. If I can modify the source, I will avoid such collision by renaming parameter names.

Comment: You can't achieve what you outline in your edit without changing  `install.packages`.

Comment: I was afraid of it being so. Okay, that really answers my question, so if you would like to incorporate that note into the answer itself, I'd gladly accept.